# adding points IDs to point scatter using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to write a program using Python 3.6 to plot a 48 points with thier x and y coordinates, and I stored their x and y coordinates in pxn and pyn lists respectively 
The problam that I want to add each point's Id on each point.
Points IDs are stored in the list that called pidn.
I wrote this code part ,

```
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(pxn,pyn, 'r+', label='Point''s Coordinates')
    pylab.legend()
    pylab.title(' Points Plotting with  X-North Direction and Y-Direction ',       loc='center', color='Blue')
    pylab.xlabel('Y-Direction', fontsize=14, color='red')
    pylab.ylabel('X-Direction',fontsize=14, color='blue')
    pylab.grid(True)
    pylab.show()
```

But I don not know how to add the Ids on each point from the pidn list.
Any one help me please, I am a beginer in Python .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the 'point ID'  on the graph. This is what would be called annotating.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,3,2]
pid = ["ID5", "IDQ", 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, ls="", marker="o")
for xi, yi, pidi in zip(x,y,pid):
    ax.annotate(str(pidi), xy=(xi,yi))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If this solves your issue, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. Instead of saying 'thank you', you may just upvote (votes will be counted once you have 15 reputation points).